# Java (swing) paint only what's viewable on the screen

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am making a tile based platformer game in java. I render a map which is stored in a 2 dimensional array but when this array is very big my game starts to become slow. I realised that I had to only render the part of the map that is viewable, I tried to do that but i wrote very hacky code that only worked partly so I removed it. How can I do this properly? Here is my code (without the hacky stuff). Also how could I use `System.nanoTime()` rather than `System.currentTimeMillis()`?

```
package sexy_robot_from_another_dimension;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.TexturePaint;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel
{
    int playerX = 50;
    int playerY = 50;
    static boolean up = false;
    static boolean down = false;
    static boolean right = false;
    static boolean left = false;
    int playerSpeed = 1;
    String[][] map;
    int blockSize = 20;
    int jumpLoop = 0;
    int maxJumpLoop = 280;
    static BufferedImage block, player;
    int playerWidth = 20;
    int playerHeight = 35;
    int cameraX = 0; 
    int cameraY = 0;
    long nextSecond = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
    int frameInLastSecond = 0;
    int framesInCurrentSecond = 0;

    public Game()
    {
        super();
        try 
        {
            map = load("/maps/map1.txt");
        } 

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {

                if(up)
                {               
                    if((!playerIsOnBlock(playerX, playerY).equals("0")) || (!playerIsOnBlock(playerX + (playerWidth - 1), playerY).equals("0")))
                    {
                        timeToJump();
                    }
                }

                if(down)
                {               
                }

                if(right)
                {
                    if((playerIsLeftBlock(playerX, playerY).equals("0")) && (playerIsLeftBlock(playerX, playerY + (playerHeight/2 - 1)).equals("0")) && (playerIsLeftBlock(playerX, playerY + (playerHeight - 1)).equals("0")))
                    {
                        playerX += playerSpeed;
                    }
                }

                if(left)
                {                   
                    if((playerIsRightBlock(playerX, playerY).equals("0")) && (playerIsRightBlock(playerX, playerY + (playerHeight/2 - 1)).equals("0")) && (playerIsRightBlock(playerX, playerY + (playerHeight - 1)).equals("0")))
                    {
                        playerX -= playerSpeed;
                    }
                }

                repaint();
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10);

        Timer timerGrav = new Timer();
        TimerTask taskGrav = new TimerTask() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                if((playerIsOnBlock(playerX, playerY).equals("0")) && (playerIsOnBlock(playerX + (playerWidth - 1), playerY).equals("0")))
                {
                    playerY += playerSpeed;
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        };
        timerGrav.scheduleAtFixedRate(taskGrav, 0, 6);
    }

    void timeToJump()
    {
        if(jumpLoop == 0)
        {
            jumpLoop = 1;
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    if((playerIsBelowBlock(playerX, playerY).equals("0")) && (playerIsBelowBlock(playerX + (playerWidth - 1), playerY).equals("0")))
                    {               
                        playerY -= playerSpeed;
                        jumpLoop++;
                        repaint();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        jumpLoop = maxJumpLoop;
                    }

                    if(jumpLoop == maxJumpLoop)
                    {
                        jumpLoop = 0;
                        cancel();
                    }
                }
            };
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 3);
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime > nextSecond) 
        {
            nextSecond += 1000;
            frameInLastSecond = framesInCurrentSecond;
            framesInCurrentSecond = 0;
        }
        framesInCurrentSecond++;

        g.drawString(frameInLastSecond + " fps", 10, 20);
        cameraX = -playerX + getWidth()/2;
        cameraY = -playerY + getHeight()/2;
        g.translate(cameraX, cameraY);
        for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < map[0].length; y++) 
            {
                switch(map[x][y])
                {
                case "0":
                    break;
                case "1":
                    if(block != null)
                    {
                        TexturePaint tp0 = new TexturePaint(block, new Rectangle(0, 0, blockSize, blockSize));
                        g2.setPaint(tp0);
                    }
                    g.fillRect(y*blockSize, x*blockSize, 20, 20);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if(player != null)
        {
            TexturePaint tp0 = new TexturePaint(player, new Rectangle(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight));
            g2.setPaint(tp0);
        }
        g.fillRect(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.setFont(new Font("Droid Sans Mono", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        g.drawString("Sexy!", playerX - 5, playerY - 10);
    }

    boolean outOfMap(int x, int y)
    {
        y -= blockSize - 1;
        x -= blockSize - 1;
        if((y/blockSize <= map.length - 2) && (y/blockSize >= 0) && (x/blockSize <= map[0].length-2) && (x/blockSize >= 0))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    String playerIsOnBlock(int x, int y)
    {
        y += playerHeight;
        if(!outOfMap(x, y))
        {
            if(map[y/blockSize][x/blockSize] != "0")
            {
                return map[y/blockSize][x/blockSize];
            }
        }
        return "0";     
    }

    String playerIsBelowBlock(int x, int y)
    {
        y -= playerSpeed;
        if(!outOfMap(x, y))
        {
            if(map[y/blockSize][x/blockSize] != "0")
            {
                return map[y/blockSize][x/blockSize];
            }
        }
        return "0";     
    }

    String playerIsLeftBlock(int x, int y)
    {
        x += playerWidth;
        if(!outOfMap(x, y))
        {
            if(map[y/blockSize][x/blockSize] != "0")
            {
                return map[y/blockSize][x/blockSize];
            }
        }
        return "0";     
    }

    String playerIsRightBlock(int x, int y)
    {
        x -= playerSpeed;
        if(!outOfMap(x, y))
        {
            if(map[y/blockSize][x/blockSize] != "0")
            {
                return map[y/blockSize][x/blockSize];
            }
        }
        return "0";     
    }


    String[][] load(String file) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)));
        int lines = 1;
        int length = br.readLine().split(" ").length;
        while (br.readLine() != null) lines++;
        br.close();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(file)));
        String[][] map = new String[lines][length];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
        {
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            for (int y = 0; y < length; y++)
            {
                map[i][y] = parts[y];
            }
        }
        br.close();
        return map;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Seems to me the problem lies in the fact, that the code is using `java.util.Timer` instead of [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), since in the latter GUI related updates are automatically done on the EDT, though in the former, a programmer has to do that manually, by wrapping the code responsible for updates inside `EventQueue.invokeLater(...)`. Moreover if the task that you are performing is a long running backghround task, then prefer [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: I use a `java.util.timer` because it is more precise than a `javax.swing.timer`

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the time from the system clock.  Never intended for extremely small measures of time, so you'll have operations taking place that may not have any measurable time between them. `nanoTime()` is a lot more precise even if converted back to milliseconds. If you need to get it back to milliseconds, wrap this in a method:
`TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.convert(System.nanoTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)`

One or the other is used by any of the timer implementations, so if you must choose one, use one backed by nano time for games.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your camera is centered on the player, then there are two ways of doing this, I like the first way, it is a bit cleaner:

1th: Create a rectangle that bounds your cameras view, and check if the map x,y is within this view, render only if true.

```
  Rectangle cameraView = new Rectangle(playerX - getWidth() / 2, playerY - getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight());
    for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < map[0].length; y++) {
            if (!cameraView.contains(x*blockSize, y*blockSize))
                continue;
            switch (map[x][y]) {
            case "0":
                break;
            case "1":
                if (block != null) {
                    TexturePaint tp0 = new TexturePaint(block, new Rectangle(0, 0, blockSize, blockSize));
                    g2.setPaint(tp0);
                }
                g.fillRect(y * blockSize, x * blockSize, 20, 20);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

The second option is to simply calculate the distance to the center of the screen `(playerX,playerY)` from each `map[x][y]` and skip all `map[x][y]` that falls outside your viewing bounds, this is a bit uglier to code and I really don't recommend this, the rectangle option above should be fast enough.

**Edit:**
@JasonC That is true, I didn't consider for instance when an x value is definitely outside the view, it will still go into the y loop through all the y values. One can simply create a dummy variable in the x-loop and do the following check

```
for (int x = 0; x < map.length; x++) {
  int dummyY = playerY
  if(!cameraView.contains(x,dummyY))
    continue;
    ....
   //rest of code ommitted
```

Another optimization you can do is considering not setting a `TexturePaint` (expensive operation) but instead simply drawing the image of the block:

```
g.fillRect(y * blockSize, x * blockSize, 20, 20);
```

Replaced with

```
g.drawImage(block, y*blockSize, x*blockSize, null);
```

The same with the playerimage.

Comment: As an additional optimization, apply the inverse of the camera transform to determine the left, right, top, and bottom edges in map block coordinates. Then you can limit the range of the for loops and avoid cameraView.contains() calls for blocks that are definitely out of range.

Comment: Wow 50 FPS but your code still has a problem I will fix it thanks

Answer (score 4):

Set the clipping region to the visible area with Graphics.setClip(), that will prevent most rendering operations from taking effect outside that region.

For drawing operations where this isn't sufficient (perhaps you also want to avoid doing calculations or something for objects outside the clipping area), test your objects bounds against the clipping rectangle and skip the object if it doesn't intersect.

See [Graphics.setClip()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setClip%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

A further optimization can be done by, for example, calculating the range of blocks on your map that is definitely outside of the visible area, and excluding that from your for loop (no sense testing blocks against the clipping region if you *know* they are outside already). Take the clipping region, transform it to map index coordinates, then you will know where in your map the visible area is and you can just iterate over that subsection of the map.

Comment: +1, as I went through this post, I liked the logic thingy so described :-). Though the upvote will come in 7 hours, as my limit for today is done with :(

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure how to calculate the range of blocks :( using setClip doubled my FPS but I'm at 10 FPS now too slow.

Comment: Do the opposite of what you do to determine the screen coordinates of a block. Apply the inverse of the camera transform to determine the left, right, top, and bottom edges in map block coordinates. Then you can limit the range of the for loops and avoid bounds checking and processing for blocks that are definitely out of range.